# Framework for static Wordpress Site/Blog - Use Foundation?

Tags: wordpress, zurb-foundation

I've been using Foundation 4 (and jumping into 5 now) for the past 6 months or so and I've created a couple responsive products and used it as a test to learn and work with SASS/Compass.

I've got a request from a client for a simple, static site - and I'm wondering if anyone who works with Foundation regularly had any advice on whether they are using foundation to create small/non-responsive sites with SASS/Compass or if they went another way with a framework.

Simple blog + 5 static pages for a small company.

Answer (score 0):

Considering it is a static, simple blog site, you could use Jekyll with GitHub Pages. All you'd need is an account on GitHub now that they let you use a custom domain. No hosting required. Foundation would work too although I prefer Semantic UI.